# jquery tablesorter plugin with mixed date format not working in IE/Safari, does work in FF,O,C

Tags: javascript, jquery, tablesorter

Not sure what the exact issue is..basically, am using the tablesorter jquery plugin, trying to sort with 2 different types of date format listings in the column. I need the end result to be a chronological sort (obviously), just like it's doing in FF now. Any insight is greatly appreciated.

http://developer.erg.com/~bzaks/test2.html

Comment: Does the example have the issue you are trying to resolve? The only date column I see is the year, and it sorts correctly.

Answer (score 0):

One of the nice things about the tablesorter plugin is that is will evaluate the column data and pick the best parser. Mixed date formats will still get parsed as dates.

Check out this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/styson/ULZnY/) and see how the Date column works.

Debugging the sort shows that the dates get parsed by the usLongDate parser, and that parser parses and converts the date string to a time integer to sort it correctly.